# Child Theme Reverts to Parent Theme After Activation: Customizations Lost

Tags: child-theme

I'm experiencing an issue with my WordPress child theme. I created a child theme based on the 'drinkify-lite' parent theme and used the provided code to enqueue the parent styles in my child theme's functions.php. However, when I activate the child theme, it seems to revert to the original parent theme, and the customizations I made on the parent theme are no longer visible.

I've double-checked the code, and it appears to be correctly enqueuing the parent styles. Is there something I might be missing or a common mistake that causes this behavior? Any guidance on how to ensure that my child theme retains the customizations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may have several underlying causes. I encourage you to create your child theme from scratch and make sure working fine without any deep customization.

Practically speaking, the child theme works fine with the `style.css` and the `functions.php` file only.

```css
/*
Theme Name:   Drinkify Lite Child
Template:     drinkify-lite
Version:      1.0.0
*/

body {
    background: green;
}
```

Create the `functions.php` file in the child directory (`drinkify-lite-child`) something similar:

```php
<?php

function drinkify_light_child_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'drinkify-lite-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'drinkify_light-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'drinkify_light_child_enqueue_styles' );

/* --------- Insert your customized functions on the next rows --------- */
```

And then add your customization functions one by one and see which one causing the problem.

Read more about the child theme [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).